Difficulties in creating accurate textures from reference image: how to handle certain areas
how do I get this texture from this image? In particular I don't understand how to make those brown/grey parts, I already tried editing the starting image on photoshop or painting directly on blender but the result is not the best and not accurate




Quite possibly like this tutorial shows, https://youtu.be/bQFX9tXMCdI?si=kZ6mA3eVxkEwpAiM, you can model a section of the weave and render it with alpha as a texture and use that as surface texture as well as alpha for creating the holes in the flat mesh.
